# Why my NSBezierPath is not showing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

So i recieve a notification with the data i need to draw my path. This code is from my main app controller:

```
-(void) handleAdd:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
NSLog(@"x1:%f y1:%f x2:%f y2:%f ",[panelController x1],[panelController y1],[panelController x2],[panelController y2]);

myPath = [[NSBezierPath alloc]init];
[myPath setLineWidth:[panelController grosor]];

[myPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint([panelController x1],[panelController y1])];
[myPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint([panelController x2],[panelController y2])];
[[panelController trazado] setStroke];
[myPath stroke];
}
```

The NSLog is showing me the right data. I have a view created and in that white rectangle is where i want to draw.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect bounds= [self bounds];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
}
```

If i draw in that class the stroke is showing, but how could i draw on that view from the controller? Or should i just receive the notification in the view and draw from that class?

Comment: All drawing must occur inside `-drawRect:`. So on `-handleAdd:` store away your data and flag the view as needeing display: `[myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];`. Lastly, you need to set a color for the bezier path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (easily) draw from the controller into the view.

Think of your views `drawRect` method as a complete set of instructions of what to draw at every refresh.

So right now all you are saying is *"fill me with white"*

You need to handle **all** the relevant drawing within the views `drawRect:` method.

Adjust your controller method to this.

```
-(void) handleAdd:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [myViewInstance setNeedsDisplay:YES]; //also myViewInstance.needsDisplay = YES
}
```

And assuming the view has a reference to the panel controller…

```
@interface MyView: UIView 

//weak as you don't want a reference cycle
@property (weak) MyPanelController *panelController;

@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect bounds= [self bounds];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];

    NSBezierPath *myPath = [[NSBezierPath alloc]init];
    [myPath setLineWidth:[self.panelController grosor]];

    [myPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint([self.panelController x1],[self.panelController y1])];
    [myPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint([self.panelController x2],[self.panelController y2])];
    [[self.panelController trazado] setStroke];
    [myPath stroke];
}

@end
```

If you want explore your first technique you want to look at at `NSView` and the `lockFocus/unlockFocus` methods. The documentation explains why you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: i get it now, but if with every refresh it will do a fillrect with white, the shapes you had before would be gone? And when you run your app, and myPath won't have anything to draw, right? Should i control that?

Comment: and one more thing, what can i do if i don't have a reference to the panel in the view?

Comment: You need to find a way to pass the relevant information to the view so that it  can draw it, whether thats by passing a reference to your `panelController` or setting up a model and using that. Your current drawing will last exactly once, its not additive. If you have 10 lines to draw you must draw them all on every cycle.